# Flex sort array collection by inner class

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, actionscript, flex4

I want to sort an array collection in a way that I am not sure is possible.

Usually when you want to sort you have something like this.

```
var dataSortField1:SortField = new SortField();
dataSortField1.name = fieldOneToSortBy;
dataSortField1.numeric = fieldOneIsNumeric;

var dataSort:Sort = new Sort();
dataSort.fields = [dataSortField1];

arrayCollection.sort = dataSort;
arrayCollection.refresh();
```

so if I had a class

```
public class ToSort {
    public var int:a
}
```

I could type

```
var ts1:ToSort = new ToSort();  
ts1.a = 10;
var ts2:ToSort = new ToSort();  
ts2.a = 20;
var arrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([ts1, ts2])
var dataSortField1:SortField = new SortField();
dataSortField1.name = "a";
dataSortField1.numeric = true;

var dataSort:Sort = new Sort();
dataSort.fields = [dataSortField1];

arrayCollection.sort = dataSort;
arrayCollection.refresh();
```

This works fine. My problem is I now have inherited a class that has another class inside it and I need to sort against this as well.
For example

```
public class ToSort2 {
    public var int:a
    public var ToSortInner: inner1
}

public class ToSortInner {
    public var int:aa
    public var int:bb
}
```

if a is the same in multiple classes then I want to sort on ToSortInner2.aa Is this possible. I have tried to pass in inner1.aa as the sort field name but this does not work.

Hope this is clear. If not I'll post some more code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom sort [compareFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/Sort.html#compareFunction).  You can drill down into the objects properties inside the function.

Conceptually something like this:

```
public function aSort(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int{
  if(a.aa is b.aa){
    return 0
  } else if(a.aa > b.aa) {
    return 1
  } else{
    return -1
  }
}
```

When you create your sort object, you can specify the compare function:

```
var dataSort:Sort = new Sort();
dataSort.compareFunction = aSort;

arrayCollection.sort = dataSort;
arrayCollection.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort also has another property, compareFunction.